# How to define the shipping cost?

Tags: woocommerce

On your single product pages you should also have a link with the text "Shipping Costs" (Or in my case the german equivalent "Versandkosten") [The shipping costs link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrAIT.jpg)
When I click on this link, a window with the same page opens. I assume that somewhere in the backend I have to define a "shipping costs overview" page.
Is that link working on your shop? Where did you define it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page "shipping costs overview" on your WordPress website and enter the contents and publish that page. Copy the URL of the published page and enter that in the below function's Anchor tag's Href.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'rf_show_shippingcost_link', 20 );

function rf_show_shippingcost_link() {
    echo '<a href="ENTER LIKE HERE" class="shipping_link">Versandkosten</a>';
}
```